# How to set bin content in a hist2d (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot values of z binned in (x,y). This would look like a hist2d in matplotlib but with the bin content being defined by another array instead of representing the number of counts. Is there any way to set the bin content in hist2d?

Comment: I would use `imshow` to plot it as a heat-map, unless you _really_ have a 3D surface (or are trying to make a point about range), a color-mapped image is almost always clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to set the bin content in hist2d but there are two alternative options.

1) You can use bar3d to define the boundaries of each bin manually but it does not always render very well.

```
hist,xbinedges,ybinedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=bins,range=range)
BinlowEdgex, BinlowEdgey = np.meshgrid(xbinedges[:-1], ybinedges[:-1])
xbinwidth = ((range[0][1]-range[0][0])/(bins[0]))
ybinwidth = ((range[1][1]-range[1][0])/(bins[1]))
ax.bar3d(BinlowEdgex.flatten(), BinlowEdgey.flatten(), np.zeros(bins[0]*bins[1]), xbinwidth*np.ones(bins[0]*bins[1]), ybinwidth*np.ones(bins[0]*bins[1]), zvalues.flatten())
```

2) You can abandon the idea of a 3d histogram and use colours for the zvalues.

```
ax.imshow(zvalues.T,extent=np.array(range).flatten(),origin='lower',interpolation = 'nearest')
```

Answer (score -4):

Do you want to set the number of elements in each bin? I think that's a bar plot rather than a histogram. So simply use `ax.bar` instead.

**EDIT** Good point by tcaswell, for multidimensional images the equivalent is `imshow` rather than `bar`.

Comment: The question is answered in the text. The link is just extra information. But I'll remove it if that stops people from downvoting. I'm not going to write an example, that's not the question.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things. Sorry you're getting downvoted.